# How to break a row into multiple rows in python?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Assume I have a sample figure like this:

```
l = [
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop A', 'In', '100', '20', '30','150', 'Out', '90', '10', '15', '115'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop B', 'In', '20', '10', '40', '70', 'Out', '10', '9', '0', '19'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop C', 'In', '42', '18', '20', '80', 'Out', '40', '10', '20', '70'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop D', 'In', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Out', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop E', 'In', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Out', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop F', 'In', '20', '19', '11', '50', 'Out', '10', '9', '5', '24'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop G', 'In', '25', '8', '33', '66', 'Out', '20', '6', '30', '56'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop H', 'In', '180', '88', '6', '274', 'Out', '170', '80', '5', '255'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop I', 'In', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Out', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Total', 'In', '387', '163', '140', '690', 'Out', '340', '124', '75', '539'],
]
```

The figures show about how many men/women/children visit a shop a day and record their in and out record. The figure above can be interpreted as below:

```
[Ppl_type, Date, Weekday, Shop, In, Men, Women, Children, Total, Out, Men, Women, Children, Total]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4tSr.png) <-- the expected result

This is the result I would like to see. Generate the above figure into excel with the header below:

```
header= ['Ppl_type', 'Date', 'Weekday', 'Shop', 'In/Out', 'Visitor_Type', 'Number']
```

As a result, each shop will have six rows (i.e. three rows for "In" and three rows for "Out") summarizing the figures above.

I would like to know how can I do it by python and generate the result to excel. I have tried *worksheet.write* but seems only work for the first four columns. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

For a fully programmatic solution, you can use:

```
header= ['Ppl_type', 'Date', 'Weekday', 'Shop',
         'In', 'Men', 'Women', 'Children', 'Total',
         'Out', 'Men', 'Women', 'Children', 'Total']

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=header)

m1 = df.columns.isin(['In', 'Out'])
grp = df.columns.to_series().where(m1).ffill()
m2 = grp.notna()
m = m2 & ~m1

out = (
 df.loc[:, m2==m]
   .set_index(list(grp[~m2].index))
   .astype(int)
   .set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns[m], grp[m]],
                                       names=('Visitor_Type', 'In/Out')), axis=1)
   .stack(['In/Out', 'Visitor_Type']).reset_index(name='Number')
   # uncomment the line below to remove the Total
   #.loc[lambda d: d['Visitor_Type'].ne('Total') 
)
```

Output:

```
    Ppl_type             Date   Weekday    Shop In/Out Visitor_Type  Number
0   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In     Children      30
1   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In          Men     100
2   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In        Total     150
3   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In        Women      20
4   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out     Children      15
5   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out          Men      90
6   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out        Total     115
7   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out        Women      10
8   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In     Children      40
9   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In          Men      20
10  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In        Total      70
...
```

Comment: if you dont mind, could you provide the original `df` - i cannot reproduce the OP's dataframe - maybe there's an error somewhere, plus your data seems different from @jezrael's

Comment: @sammywemmy I just used OP's data adding the missing commas and one missing quote, I'll update their question

Answer (score 2):

You can change columns names with `1` and `2` for deduplicted columns names, so possible use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape if need order of original data:

```
L = [['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop A', 'In', '100', '20', '30','150', 'Out', '90', '10', '15', '115'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop B', 'In', '20', '10', '40', '70', 'Out', '10', '9', '0', '19'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop C', 'In', '42', '18', '20', '80', 'Out', '40', '10', '20', '70'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop D', 'In', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Out', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop E', 'In', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Out', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop F', 'In', '20', '19', '11', '50', 'Out', '10', '9', '5', '24'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop G', 'In', '25', '8', '33', '66', 'Out', '20', '6', '30', '56'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop H', 'In', '180', '88', '6', '274', 'Out', '170', '80', '5', '255'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop I', 'In', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Out', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Total', 'In', '387', '163', '140', '690', 'Out', '340', '124', '75', '539']]
```

---

```
cols = ['Ppl_type', 'Date', 'Weekday', 'Shop', 
        'In/Out1', 'Men1', 'Women1', 'Children1', 'Total1', 
        'In/Out2', 'Men2', 'Women2', 'Children2', 'Total2']
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=cols)
```

If original columns names are duplicited add `1` and `2`:

```
cols = ['Ppl_type', 'Date', 'Weekday', 'Shop', 
        'In', 'Men', 'Women', 'Children', 'Total', 
        'Out', 'Men', 'Women', 'Children', 'Total']
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=cols)


c = ['Ppl_type', 'Date', 'Weekday', 'Shop','In','Out']

df.columns += (df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
                   .mask(df.columns.isin(c),''))


df = df.rename(columns={'In':'In/Out','Out':'In/Out'})
print (df.head(3))
   Ppl_type             Date   Weekday    Shop In/Out Men1 Women1 Children1  \
0  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In  100     20        30   
1  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In   20     10        40   
2  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C     In   42     18        20   

  Total1 In/Out Men2 Women2 Children2 Total2  
0    150    Out   90     10        15    115  
1     70    Out   10      9         0     19  
2     80    Out   40     10        20     70
```

---

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                      stubnames=['In/Out','Men','Women','Children','Total'], 
                      i=['Ppl_type', 'Date', 'Weekday', 'Shop'],
                      j='tmp').set_index('In/Out', append=True)
        .droplevel(-2)
        .rename_axis('Visitor_Type', axis=1)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='Number'))

print (df1)
    Ppl_type             Date   Weekday    Shop In/Out Visitor_Type Number
0   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In          Men    100
1   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In        Women     20
2   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In     Children     30
3   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In        Total    150
4   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out          Men     90
..       ...              ...       ...     ...    ...          ...    ...
75  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total     In        Total    690
76  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total    Out          Men    340
77  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total    Out        Women    124
78  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total    Out     Children     75
79  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total    Out        Total    539

[80 rows x 7 columns]
```

If need remove `Total` in final output:

```
df2 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.drop(['Total1','Total2'], axis=1), 
                      stubnames=['In/Out','Men','Women','Children'], 
                      i=['Ppl_type', 'Date', 'Weekday', 'Shop'],
                      j='tmp').set_index('In/Out', append=True)
        .droplevel(-2)
        .rename_axis('Visitor_Type', axis=1)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='Number'))

print (df2.head(10))
   Ppl_type             Date   Weekday    Shop In/Out Visitor_Type Number
0  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In          Men    100
1  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In        Women     20
2  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In     Children     30
3  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out          Men     90
4  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out        Women     10
5  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out     Children     15
6  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In          Men     20
7  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In        Women     10
8  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In     Children     40
9  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B    Out          Men     10
```

Comment: Thank you. May I know why I get the error  "ValueError: Length of passed values is 14, index implies 10." by running the above? Besides, how do I separate "In" and "Out" ? (like under header "In/Out", three rows is "In" and three rows is "Out")

Comment: @pooncl - What part of solution failed?

Comment: my fault. it success now, thank you

Comment: @pooncl - I simplify solution, can you check?

Answer (score 1):

To break a row into multiple rows in Python, you can use the split() method to split a string into a list of substrings based on a specified delimiter. Here's an example code snippet:

```
row = "John,Smith,25,New York"
   delimiter = ","
   split_row = row.split(delimiter)
        print(split_row)
```

n this example, the row variable contains a string with four values separated by a comma. We define the delimiter variable to be a comma, which we will use to split the row. Then, we use the split() method on the row variable with the delimiter argument to split the string into a list of substrings. The resulting split_row list will contain four elements: "John", "Smith", "25", and "New York".

Once you have a list of substrings, you can use them to create multiple rows. For example, you could use a loop to iterate over the list and create a new row for each value:

for value in split_row:
new_row = value
print(new_row)
This will create a new row for each value in the split_row list. The resulting output will be:

John
Smith
25
New York

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode a parser for this:

```
def split_rows(row):
    base = [row[0], parsed_date(row[1]), row[2], row[3]]
    return [
        base + ['In', 'Man', row[5]],
        base + ['In', 'Woman', row[6]],
        base + ['In', 'Children', row[7]],
        base + ['Out', 'Man', row[10]],
        base + ['Out', 'Woman', row[11]],
        base + ['Out', 'Children', row[12]]
    ]
```

Then assuming data is a list of lists containing the data:

```
final_rows = []
for d in data:
    for row in split_rows(d):
        final_rows.append(row)

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(final_rows)
```

Then just implement parsed_date

PS: the other solution posted while I wrote this are definitely better than this

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) - in this case we want the headers (men, women, children) lumped into a `visitor_type` column, and the values lumped into a `number` column - we take that pattern and reshape accordingly:

```py
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = ['Ppl_type', 'Date', 'Weekday', 'Shop', 'In', 'Out'], 
    names_to = ['Visitor_Type'], 
    values_to = ['Number'], 
    names_pattern = ['.+n'],
    sort_by_appearance=True)
.assign(In_Out = lambda f: np.where(f.index%2, 'Out', 'In'))
.drop(columns = ['In', 'Out'])
.astype({'Number':int})
)

    Ppl_type             Date   Weekday    Shop Visitor_Type Number In_Out
0   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A          Men    100     In
1   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A          Men     90    Out
2   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A        Women     20     In
3   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A        Women     10    Out
4   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     Children     30     In
5   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     Children     15    Out
6   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B          Men     20     In
7   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B          Men     10    Out
8   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B        Women     10     In
9   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B        Women      9    Out
10  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     Children     40     In
11  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     Children      0    Out
12  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C          Men     42     In
13  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C          Men     40    Out
14  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C        Women     18     In
15  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C        Women     10    Out
16  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C     Children     20     In
17  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C     Children     20    Out
18  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D          Men      0     In
19  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D          Men      0    Out
20  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D        Women      0     In
21  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D        Women      0    Out
22  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D     Children      0     In
23  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D     Children      0    Out
24  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E          Men      0     In
25  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E          Men      0    Out
26  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E        Women      0     In
27  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E        Women      0    Out
28  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E     Children      0     In
29  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E     Children      0    Out
30  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F          Men     20     In
31  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F          Men     10    Out
32  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F        Women     19     In
33  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F        Women      9    Out
34  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F     Children     11     In
35  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F     Children      5    Out
36  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G          Men     25     In
37  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G          Men     20    Out
38  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G        Women      8     In
39  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G        Women      6    Out
40  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G     Children     33     In
41  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G     Children     30    Out
42  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H          Men    180     In
43  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H          Men    170    Out
44  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H        Women     88     In
45  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H        Women     80    Out
46  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H     Children      6     In
47  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H     Children      5    Out
48  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I          Men      0     In
49  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I          Men      0    Out
50  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I        Women      0     In
51  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I        Women      0    Out
52  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I     Children      0     In
53  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I     Children      0    Out
54  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total          Men    387     In
55  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total          Men    340    Out
56  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total        Women    163     In
57  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total        Women    124    Out
58  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total     Children    140     In
59  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total     Children     75    Out
```

Another option is with stack - since the data has a predictable form ('men', women', 'children') we can take advantage of that, reshape in numpy, return to pandas and finish the job:

```py
index = df.columns[:4].tolist()
out = df.set_index(index).drop(columns='Total')
columns = ['In_Out', 'Men', "Women", 'Children']
frame = out.to_numpy().reshape(-1, len(columns))
# reshape above was done in a C order, so repeat is fine here
# we are sure of the alignment
index = out.index.repeat(out.columns.size//len(columns))
(pd
.DataFrame(
    frame, 
    columns = columns, 
    index = index)
.set_index('In_Out', append=True)
.stack()
.rename_axis(index = list(index.names) + ['In_Out', 'visitor_type'])
.rename('Number')
.reset_index()
)

    Ppl_type             Date   Weekday    Shop In_Out visitor_type Number
0   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In          Men    100
1   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In        Women     20
2   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A     In     Children     30
3   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out          Men     90
4   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out        Women     10
5   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop A    Out     Children     15
6   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In          Men     20
7   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In        Women     10
8   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B     In     Children     40
9   Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B    Out          Men     10
10  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B    Out        Women      9
11  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop B    Out     Children      0
12  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C     In          Men     42
13  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C     In        Women     18
14  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C     In     Children     20
15  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C    Out          Men     40
16  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C    Out        Women     10
17  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop C    Out     Children     20
18  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D     In          Men      0
19  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D     In        Women      0
20  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D     In     Children      0
21  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D    Out          Men      0
22  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D    Out        Women      0
23  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop D    Out     Children      0
24  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E     In          Men      0
25  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E     In        Women      0
26  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E     In     Children      0
27  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E    Out          Men      0
28  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E    Out        Women      0
29  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop E    Out     Children      0
30  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F     In          Men     20
31  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F     In        Women     19
32  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F     In     Children     11
33  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F    Out          Men     10
34  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F    Out        Women      9
35  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop F    Out     Children      5
36  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G     In          Men     25
37  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G     In        Women      8
38  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G     In     Children     33
39  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G    Out          Men     20
40  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G    Out        Women      6
41  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop G    Out     Children     30
42  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H     In          Men    180
43  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H     In        Women     88
44  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H     In     Children      6
45  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H    Out          Men    170
46  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H    Out        Women     80
47  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop H    Out     Children      5
48  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I     In          Men      0
49  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I     In        Women      0
50  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I     In     Children      0
51  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I    Out          Men      0
52  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I    Out        Women      0
53  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday  Shop I    Out     Children      0
54  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total     In          Men    387
55  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total     In        Women    163
56  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total     In     Children    140
57  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total    Out          Men    340
58  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total    Out        Women    124
59  Visitors  1 February 2020  Saturday   Total    Out     Children     75
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
header= ['Ppl_type', 'Date', 'Weekday', 'Shop',
         'In', 'Men', 'Women', 'Children', 'Total',
         'Out', 'Men', 'Women', 'Children', 'Total']
data = [['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop A', 'In', '100', '20', '30','150', 'Out', '90', '10', '15', '115'],
        ['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop B', 'In', '20', '10', '40', '70', 'Out', '10', '9', '0', '19'],
        ['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop C', 'In', '42', '18', '20', '80', 'Out', '40', '10', '20', '70'],
        ['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop D', 'In', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Out', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop E', 'In', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Out', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop F', 'In', '20', '19', '11', '50', 'Out', '10', '9', '5', '24'],
        ['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop G', 'In', '25', '8', '33', '66', 'Out', '20', '6', '30', '56'],
        ['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop H', 'In', '180', '88', '6', '274', 'Out', '170', '80', '5', '255'],
        ['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Shop I', 'In', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Out', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['Visitors', '1 February 2020', 'Saturday', 'Total', 'In', '387', '163', '140', '690', 'Out', '340', '124', '75', '539']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
```

```
tmp = df.set_index(header[:4])
mask = tmp.columns.isin(['In', 'Out'])
cols_lv0 = [*tmp.columns.where(mask).to_series().ffill()]
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [cols_lv0, tmp.columns.tolist()],
    names=['In_Out', 'Visitor_Type']
)
result = (tmp.set_axis(cols, axis=1)
          .loc[:, ~mask]
          .drop('Total', level=1, axis=1)
          .stack([0, 1])
          .reset_index(name='Number'))
print(result)
>>>
    Ppl_type    Date            Weekday     Shop    In_Out  Visitor_Type    Number
0   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop A  In      Children       30
1   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop A  In      Men            100
2   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop A  In      Women          20
3   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop A  Out     Children       15
4   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop A  Out     Men            90
5   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop A  Out     Women          10
6   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop B  In      Children       40
7   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop B  In      Men            20
8   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop B  In      Women          10
9   Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop B  Out     Children       0
10  Visitors    1 February 2020 Saturday    Shop B  Out     Men            10
...
```